# How to sign a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I converting Rails plugin to ruby gem with echoe. 
When I execute

```
rake install
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Private key not found; gem will not be signed.
```

What do I have to do to make a signed gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the docs.

The url to this help page recently changed, here's the new url: http://guides.rubygems.org/security/